# Update table data tag and Html:hidden field values using Ajax call

Tags: java, html, ajax, jsp

I want to update table data tag and HTML hidden field based on ajax result[image]

**Ajax result**

```
 if(jsonObj.result =="Nomarket")
    {
    alert(jsonObj.result);
    //SET VALUE TO releaseidTD and Hidden field
    var tdElem = document.getElementById ("releaseIdTD" );
       tdElem =jsonObj.result;

    }else
    {
    alert(jsonObj.result);
var tdElem = document.getElementById ("releaseIdTD" );
       tdElem =jsonObj.result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to update the html of the element

```
document.getElementById("releaseIdTD").innerHTML= jsonObj.result;
```